# Behavior inconsistency of flask development server on Linux and Mac OS X

Tags: python, linux, macos, flask

I'm writing some test cases for a flask application.

This application has a blueprint like this:

```
@api_blueprint.route('/api/search/', methods=['GET'])
def search():
   ...
```

My test is trying to verify that a request like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/search
```

returns a status code 301

This test is working fine on a CentOS 6 server (and on any other linux machine I tried)

In fact a very simple get requests gives the right result:

```
In [1]: import requests
In [2]: r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/search')
Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
In [3]: r.history
Out[3]: (<Response [301]>,)
```

but it is failing on my Mac Pro with Mac OS X 10.6.8 and python 2.6 installed through MacPorts.

on the Mac the same simple requests gives directly a status code 200:

```
In [1]: import requests
In [2]: r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/search')
Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
In [3]: r.history
Out[3]: []
In [4]: r.status_code
Out[4]: 200
```

Obviously I already checked that I have the same version of Flask on both machines.

Anybody knows why there is this annoying difference in behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: In all likelihood the answer is in the code for the `search()` view which you omitted.

Comment: No, the behavior is independent from the view. I just tested the view
@api_blueprint.route('/search_tmp/', methods=['GET'])
def search_tmp():
    return 'foobar'
And it gives back the same status code.

Comment: On Linux `search_tmp()` gives you a 301? It's *supposed* to return a 200 status.

Comment: On linux it gives first 301 and then 200. On Mac directly 200

Comment: Ciao Giovanni ;-) Would you please give us your `requests` versions, on both OS?

Comment: pip freeze | grep requests
requests==1.1.0
But I don't think it's a problem of requests, since the flask testing environment gives the same result.

Comment: Uhm... No clue. `werkzeug` version?